# What is the best way to run own server side programs on ubuntu server

Tags: server, programming

If I make some server side programs with node.js / Java / Python what is the best way to run them and make them run every time I boot my server. Is crontab @reboot valid way to do this. If so how do I start and stop those so I can modify code without having to reboot server?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever method you prefer but it sometimes depends on what that software you made is used for.

Though I would not use crontab (ie. `crontab -e`) but `/etc/crontab` if you want to go that way. You can specify a user in that file but it can also be used normally (ie. edits to `/etc/crontab` are in effect immediately) and you can also use things like `@reboot`. It is a very common method to use so if you like that go for it.

You could also create a service (with options start, stop, restart as apache or mysql have). Using [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) is an option. Another [example upstart script](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/) with node.js.

Comment: Hey, thanks I did go with upstart script and that seems to work the way I wanted. At least it worked with node.js probably I can manage it to get work with Java and Python too.

Comment: Yes it will be possible with java and python too. The "forever" scripts are nice to work with too :)